# Is there any way to integrate SharePoint lists with a website/web application to perform READ/WRITE operations?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating a PHP Web Application/Site. I need to store some data on sharepoint lists and retrieve them to show on the web application/site.
Is there any way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [API](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API) :

**Usage:**

```
use Thybag\SharePointAPI;
$sp = new SharePointAPI('<username>', '<password>', '<path_to_WSDL>');
```

**Reading from list:**

```
$sp->read('<list_name>');
```

**Querying a list:**

```
$sp->query('list of pets')->where('type','=','dog')->and_where('age','<','5')->sort('age','ASC')->get();
```

**Adding to a list:**

```
$sp->write('<list_name>', array('forename'=>'Bob','surname' =>'Smith', 'age'=>40, 'phone'=>'(00000) 000000' ));
```

And many other optionst, you can check in the link above.